# Fuelphp Permanently Deleting with Model_Soft

Tags: php, orm, fuelphp

I'm using Fuelphp (1.7.1) with Orm Model_Soft for deleting and restoring entry's. Now i've tried to permanently delete entrys with the purge() function, like provided at the documentation. This function always return false, either if the entry is softdeleted or not.
For testing i have created a simple project with no relations, there is also the same Problem. Does anyone have an idea what's wrong?

```
$post = Model_Post::find($id);
$post->purge();
```

does the same like: $post->delete()

```
$post = Model_Post::find_deleted($id);
$post->purge
```

updates only the deleted-timestamp, but does not remove the entry from DB.

example controler:

```
public function action_delete($id = null)
{
    is_null($id) and Response::redirect('posts');

    if ($post = Model_Post::find($id)){
        //$post->delete();
        if($post->purge()==false){
            Session::set_flash('error', 'error during deleting');
            Response::redirect('posts');
        }
        Session::set_flash('success', 'Deleted post #'.$id);
    }
    else{
        Session::set_flash('error', 'Could not delete post #'.$id);
    }
    Response::redirect('posts');
}
```

Comment: What version of fuel are you running?

Comment: Looking at the code `Model_Soft::purge()` simply makes a call to `parent::delete()` so there should not be any soft delete interaction happening. Are you sure it's not something else you are doing? (Looking at the [1.8/develop code](https://github.com/fuel/orm/blob/9e15948aafe65802f9505effa89fa768e8901de0/classes/model/soft.php#L175))

Comment: I use Fuelphp 1.7.1 , just updated it a few day's ago.

Comment: Try updating your orm package to 1.8/develop, I'll take a look too because I think this might be a bug in the soft delete model.

Comment: Having looked into the 1.8/develop code for `Model_Soft` I can't see any obvious bugs as the base `Model` does not make any calls back to `Model_Soft` after `purge()` has been called.

Comment: I've tried it with Orm 1.8/develop and it has the same result.

Comment: When I disable `$this->delete_self()` (Orm/Classes/Model.php,line 1472) nothing happens. So the next i've tried was disabling the `$query->delete()` (Orm/Classes/Model.php,line:1543), the result was that the deleted field was filled with the timestamp like the normal soft-delete.

Comment: In that case I think I know what is causing this issue. I should have some time to fix it over the weekend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug with the base `Model_Soft` class and has been fixed in [this commit](https://github.com/fuel/orm/commit/935528410beba8bbddca7aa5e7ba4f98c3304ad1). Update your ORM package to the latest `1.8/develop` and this issue will be solved.